# Google Sign in Error -Firebase android codelab

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I have tried this a lot of times, retrying and following the exact steps in the Firebase Android Codelab. I'm trying to login with a google account, but for some reason it is unsuccessful.

**SignInActivity.java**:

```
package com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private SignInButton mSignInButton;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // Firebase instance variables

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        // Initialize FirebaseAuth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // Assign fields
        mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

        // Set click listeners
        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // Initialize FirebaseAuth
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
        }
    }
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In failed." + result.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGooogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I *HAVE* added my SHA1 key.
And the google sign in result is: `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult@4211cac8`

I previously got an error code like this: `Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}`
But I'm pretty sure `statusCode` was different, and since I lost that error I can't find it. It would be good if someone could tell me how to redo it so I can add information.

**Logcat ("error" tagged):**(I'm sure this is useless)

```
    06-12 22:07:09.353 5049-5064/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat-6.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat-6, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-12 22:07:09.363 5049-5064/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat-6.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat-6, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-12 22:07:09.543 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.crash.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat-6.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat-6, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-12 22:07:09.693 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:09.693 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:09.693 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:09.693 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:09.703 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:09.703 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:09.703 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:09.713 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:09.723 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:09.723 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:09.733 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.MainActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:10.073 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.SignInActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:10.073 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.SignInActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:10.073 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.SignInActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:10.073 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.SignInActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:10.083 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.SignInActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:10.083 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.SignInActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:10.083 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.SignInActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:10.083 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.SignInActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:10.093 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.SignInActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:10.093 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.SignInActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:10.093 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.SignInActivity.access$super
06-12 22:07:20.113 5049-5064/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat-6.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat-6, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-12 22:07:32.205 5049-5049/com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat E/SignInActivity: Google Sign In failed.com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult@42106be8
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a great way to debug your application, since we cannot see what's happening in your code. What is working and what isn't? Did you already step through the code and see what methods get invoked? Did you check what shows up in you logcat?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey and sorry for the uninformative question.  I don't think anything shows up about this, and apparently it gets unsuccessful at `onActivityResult(...)`, at the line `if(result.isSuccess())`, because `result` is not successful. I will edit the post and include my logcat. I'd like to thank you for not downvoting my question and asking for clarification.

Comment: you are not integrated google in app.first you integrate google plus..and add google-json in your project. last line of your logcat...  Google Sign In failed.com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult@42106be8

Comment: @WaqarYounis Hey, what do you mean by integrate google plus? You mean turn it on in firebase? I already did. I added google-json too already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was something wrong in my Google-services.json , re-downloaded and it solved my problem.

Comment: did you redownload from firebase or from google cloud?

Comment: mine didn't solve it. haha. gotta find another way. thanks!

Comment: Nah, problem was that there was another app in Google Cloud with the same SHA1. So I fixed it by deleting the project in firebase and adding the one from Google Cloud. After that it still didn't work, i updated the json from Firebase like 3 times. Problem was that, I think, when you re run an already installed app is that it doesn't updated the json. So an uninstall and reinstall fixed it. And i would've upvoted your question if it was useful, but it wasnt, and I don't like how you implied that it was. Lol

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error. so,re-downloaded and it didn't solved my problem. and it resolved doing these steps.

**Android Studio**, open the **Gradle** menu on the far right, open **android-start** from the drop down (refresh if nothing is showing), open **Tasks**, open **android**, double click **signingReport**. see [this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_9tk7ME4ZU)

Get your SHA1 key from there, and go create a new Firebase project and in the console, use that SHA1 key after clicked "Add firebase to Android".. follow the tutorial from there. *Restart your device*,

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but i'll answer anyway because none of the replies worked for me.

I had the exact same error cause by the build config. Make sure you use the
`import com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.BuildConfig` instead of any other library such as firebase auth BuildConfig