# Firebase sample not logging in via Google Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried the sample chat app using Firebase in the docs but every time it gives a signing error via Google.

I have created an app in the Firebase Console with the same package. I have also pasted the `google-services.json` file in the directory. This is the [link](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/tree/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/codelab/friendlychat) for the code(6 java files).

I have pasted the same code in the above link. Here's the log:

```
    09-30 07:47:13.674 16772-16772/razor.firebasechat D/AutoManageHelper: onStart true {0=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpk$zza@c91c0e7}
    09-30 07:47:13.677 16772-16772/razor.firebasechat D/AppTracker: App Event: start
    09-30 07:47:22.051 16772-16772/razor.firebasechat D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
    09-30 07:47:22.092 16772-16772/razor.firebasechat D/AppTracker: App Event: start
    09-30 07:47:22.143 16772-16772/razor.firebasechat D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
    09-30 07:47:22.162 16772-16772/razor.firebasechat D/AbstractTracker: Event success
    09-30 07:47:22.163 16772-16772/razor.firebasechat D/AbstractTracker: Event success
    09-30 07:47:22.204 16772-16772/razor.firebasechat D/AbstractTracker: Event success
    09-30 07:47:24.664 16772-16772/razor.firebasechat E/SignInActivity: Google Sign In failed.
    09-30 07:47:24.664 16772-16772/razor.firebasechat D/AppTracker: App Event: start
    09-30 07:47:24.712 16772-16772/razor.firebasechat D/AbstractTracker: Event success
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly a problem with your SHA-1 key.  See this issue: https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/issues/11

Comment: Also see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37774230/4815718

Comment: Please let us know if your **SHA-1 key** is properly configured as pointed out by @qbix and also you have **enabled** Google-Sign in on firebase console.

Comment: Thank you @qbix, I got it working, after updating the SHA-1 key.